Como hago para que no se active el comando del botón cuando inicio el codigo?
Estoy haciendo un tres en raya y lo he hecho con nueve botones y se supone que cuando presiono un boton pues se activa la funcion con los parametros de fila y columna del boton correspondiente que he pulsado por ejemplo si pulso el de arriba a la izquierda el comando seria: moure(0,0). Y cada boton tiene sus parámetros para la función moure(). El problema es que al iniciar el código se activan todos los botones sin que los haya pulsado. Como puedo hacer que no se activen?
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, simpledialog
import random

class TresEnRatlla:

def __init__(self, root):
    
    self.taulell = [[' ',' ',' ',],[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ']]    #print(self.taulell[1][2])
    self.jugador_actual = ('X')
    self.jugador_1 = ("X")
    self.jugador_2 = ("O")
    
    self.finestra = root
    self.finestra.geometry('239x258')#ancho x alto
    self.finestra.title('Tres en Ratlla')
    
    self.b00 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[0][0],height=5,width=10, command=self.moure(0,0))
    self.b01 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[0][1],height=5,width=10, command=self.moure(0,1))
    self.b02 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[0][2],height=5,width=10, command=self.moure(0,2))
    self.b10 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[1][0],height=5,width=10, command=self.moure(1,0))
    self.b11 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[1][1],height=5,width=10, command=self.moure(1,1))
    self.b12 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[1][2],height=5,width=10, command=self.moure(1,2))
    self.b20 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[2][0],height=5,width=10, command=self.moure(2,0))
    self.b21 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[2][1],height=5,width=10, command=self.moure(2,1))
    self.b22 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[2][2],height=5,width=10, command=self.moure(2,2))
     
    self.b00.grid(row=0, column=0)
    self.b01.grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.b02.grid(row=0, column=2)
    self.b10.grid(row=1, column=0)
    self.b11.grid(row=1, column=1)
    self.b12.grid(row=1, column=2)
    self.b20.grid(row=2, column=0)
    self.b21.grid(row=2, column=1)
    self.b22.grid(row=2, column=2)
    

def moure(self, fila, columna):
      
    moviment_realitzat = False
      
    while moviment_realitzat==False:
          
        if self.taulell[fila][columna] != (' '):
            moviment_realitzat = False 
          
        else:
            self.taulell[fila][columna] = self.jugador_actual
            moviment_realitzat = True
            #self.actualitzar_taulell()
            self.passar_torn()
          
          
      
    return moviment_realitzat
        
    


def passar_torn(self):
    
    self.verificar_victoria()
    if self.verificar_victoria()==False:
        self.verificar_empat()
        if self.verificar_empat()==False:
            if self.jugador_actual==self.jugador_1:
                self.jugador_actual=self.jugador_2
            elif self.jugador_actual==self.jugador_2:
                self.jugador_actual=self.jugador_1
        
           
root=tk.Tk()
app=TresEnRatlla(root)
root.mainloop()'''


A command le debes pasar una referencia a un callable, si haces:
command=self.moure(0,0)

estás llamando al método y lo que le pasas al argumento command es una referencia al retorno del método self.moure, un bool en tu caso.
Tkinter no soporta el paso de argumentos propios de la callback por si mismo, por lo que la solución suele pasar por envolverla en otra función. Se puede usar una función lambda:
    self.b00 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[0][0],height=5,width=10, command=lambda: self.moure(0, 0))
    self.b01 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[0][1],height=5,width=10, command=lambda: self.moure(0, 1))
    self.b02 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[0][2],height=5,width=10, command=lambda: self.moure(0, 2))
    self.b10 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[1][0],height=5,width=10, command=lambda: self.moure(1, 0))
    self.b11 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[1][1],height=5,width=10, command=lambda: self.moure(1, 1))
    self.b12 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[1][2],height=5,width=10, command=lambda: self.moure(1, 2))
    self.b20 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[2][0],height=5,width=10, command=lambda: self.moure(2, 0))
    self.b21 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[2][1],height=5,width=10, command=lambda: self.moure(2, 1))
    self.b22 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[2][2],height=5,width=10, command=lambda: self.moure(2, 2))


Tengase en cuenta que la expresión de la función lambda se evalúa al ser llamada (cuando se hace click en el botón), no cuando es definida. En este caso eso no tiene importancia alguna, pero puede causar problemas en otros casos:
Problemas con los botones de Tkinter

O hacer uso de functools.partial:
# Agrega el import
from functools import partial

# ...

    self.b00 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[0][0],height=5,width=10, command=partial(self.moure, 0, 0))
    self.b01 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[0][1],height=5,width=10, command=partial(self.moure, 0, 1))
    self.b02 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[0][2],height=5,width=10, command=partial(self.moure, 0, 2))
    self.b10 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[1][0],height=5,width=10, command=partial(self.moure, 1, 0))
    self.b11 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[1][1],height=5,width=10, command=partial(self.moure, 1, 1))
    self.b12 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[1][2],height=5,width=10, command=partial(self.moure, 1, 2))
    self.b20 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[2][0],height=5,width=10, command=partial(self.moure, 2, 0))
    self.b21 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[2][1],height=5,width=10, command=partial(self.moure, 2, 1))
    self.b22 = tk.Button(self.finestra,text=self.taulell[2][2],height=5,width=10, command=partial(self.moure, 2, 2))

partial() es más eficiente y evita el mencionado problema de la evaluación de los argumentos en tiempo de ejecución de las funciones anónimas.

Muchas gracias, ya funciona
